# Why different versions for PostgreSQL displayed?

Tags: postgresql

When I execute in terminal

```
psql -V
```

It outputs:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 13.2 (Ubuntu 13.2-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

When I execute in psql prompt

```
SELECT version();
```

It outputs:

```
PostgreSQL 11.11 (Ubuntu 11.11-1.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit
```

What does it mean? Why there is different version? Which is the actual version? How do I make sure both have same version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`psql -v` gives you the version of the (client side) command line tool (running on your computer).

`select version();` gives your the version of the server you are connected to.

Your output means you are using `psql` 13 to connect to a database server running PostgreSQL 11.

If you want both to be the same version you either need to downgrade your local installation or upgrade the server to 13 (which is what I would do)